# How to simultaneously find indexPath of both tableViewCell in the case of a tableView inside another tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using tableViews inside tableView(Cells) and would like to find out the `indexPath` of both the inner `tableViewCell` and the outer `tableViewCell`.

Inside the `didSelectForRow` method (for example) I can easily access either the outer or inner `tableView` using tags, but only one `tableView` is accessible at a time, so I can't get both the inner and the outer `tableViewCell` indexPaths simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `cellForRowAt` of the parent table

```
let cell = //
cell.innerTbl.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then inside `didSelectRowAt` of the inner Tbl

```
print("parent row is : ",tableView.tag," child row is : ",indexPath.row)
```